# How to add jQuery file to navigation website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with this demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/setting-active-states-on-sticky-navigations-while-scrolling/

For some reason when I try to recreate it the Java part making the navigation work isn't coming through on my version here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ydsxavxy

So far I saved out index.html, style.css, and flip.js and attempted to link the CSS and JS in the index.

How can I get my version working like the demo? How is a Java file included outside of CSSDeck? I am not too familiar with how CSSDeck takes the HTML, CSS, and Java and combines them into one page preview.

Comment: `Java:JavaScript::ham:hamster`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of jQuery you are loading is not correct.

The example that works uses `1.8`, and you are loading `1.4`:

```
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can easily know this by looking at your browser console and seeing what errors it's throwing.  In your case, the error is as follows:

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

This usually means your jQuery library is not defined or not supported by the code you're using.

Comment: He's not missing jquery, he's using 1.4, possibly trying to call a function where the dependency isn't met? `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Comment: Ah, correct.  The version of jQuery he's using isn't correct.  Using 1.8 fixes the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's been driving be crazy what was wrong with it! I really appreciate the help!